# Reading GRUB2 debug logs

Tags: grub, grub2

I want to see GRUB2 debug logs generated by grub_dprintf(), for example, at mmap.c:

```
  grub_dprintf ("mmap", "EFI memory region 0x%llx-0x%llx: %d\n",
        (unsigned long long) desc->physical_start,
        (unsigned long long) desc->physical_start
        + desc->num_pages * 4096, desc->type);
```

After some research, I found out the way to enable this log is by setting debug env variable at grub menu (I changed it on grub.cfg, probably am not supposed to do this)

```
set debug=all
```

How can I check the logs?  The grub logs scrolled so fast during boot that it is hard to check.  Perhaps there is a way to check the logs after kernel boots?

I am using CENTOS 7.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect GRUB2 debug output to the COM1 (ttyS0) ?

Answer (score 5):

Probably too late to be useful, but you could try:

```
set pager=1
```

Comment: I have it set, the errors still get scrolled immediately before grub goes into booting a system or to menu.